# Windows remove DNS server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, powershell

I have a DNS server that is misbehaving.

Some of my windows machines only have 2 dns servers

```
server01  192.0.2.1
server02  192.0.2.2
```

Some of my windows machines have 3 dns servers

```
server01 192.0.2.1
server02 192.0.2.2
server03 192.0.2.3
```

How can I remove server03 (192.0.2.3) from my dns settings using powershell?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-DnsClientServerAddress

InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses
                             Index     Family
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------
Ethernet 2                          12 IPv4    {192.0.2.1, 192.0.2.2, 192.0.2.3}
Ethernet 2                          12 IPv6    {}
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1          1 IPv4    {}
```

I have very little windows experience. On linux, I would edit the resolv.conf

**Update** These are windows 2012 R2 servers

Comment: Actually, also on linux chances are that your /etc/resolv.conf has a line `#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`

Comment: I would say.... find out why some clients have this third address... dont remove it! look at your DHCP, seems like you have a problem with the subnet settings.

Answer (score 2):

See http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings.aspx

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'"
$DnsServers = "192.0.2.1", "192.0.2.2"
$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DnsServers)
```

Comment: If all of the machines are Windows 8 or 2012, you could use Set-DnsClientServerAddress, but I'm assuming you have some older OSes in the mix.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work for some reason if you use `SetDNSServerSearchOrder("192.0.2.1", "192.0.2.2")` so you have to assign the data to a variable.